# how to push value to key object jquery

Tags: object, push

For Example:

```
{a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
```

now:
add 33 to b

```
{a: '1', b: '2,33', c: '3'}
```

Comment: I believe this is not jquery but rather javascript specific. To add a new property to an object just use the bracket operator. E.g.: var a = {}; a["my_property"] = 1.